# Mean vectors per type in a matrix in R software

Tags: r

I have this matrix:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  type
1   1   76  7   8   54  a
2   2   67  7   8   57  a
3   3   67  5757    7557    6867    a
4   43  4   57  79  85  b
5   56  4   76  79  6   c
6   54  1   76  7   8   c
```

I want to obtain only one row per type and those rows should be the mean among the all the rows belonging to the same type:

```
        V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  type
   2    2   70  1923    2524    2326    a
   4    43  4   57  79  85  b
   2    21.5    2   28.5    39.5    42.5    c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  type
1   1   76  7   8   54  a
2   2   67  7   8   57  a
3   3   67  5757    7557    6867    a
4   43  4   57  79  85  b
5   56  4   76  79  6   c
6   54  1   76  7   8   c", header=TRUE)

aggregate(.~type, data=DF, mean)

#  type V1   V2       V3       V4   V5
#1    a  2 70.0 1923.667 2524.333 2326
#2    b 43  4.0   57.000   79.000   85
#3    c 55  2.5   76.000   43.000    7
```

Comment: Thank you Roland. Very helpful. Solved